# Запятые вокруг "в том числе"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужны ли запятые вокруг "в том числе"? Мне кажется, что нет, но не могу найти правило.

> Несомненно, эти изменения происходят в том числе и в связи с кризисными явлениями в экономике.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятые не нужны.
Кстати, если "в том числе" заменить на "в частности", то смысл изменится, а запятые все равно не нужны. Но "в частности" и "в связи", расположенные рядом, – коряво.

Comment: Парадокс в том, что смысл этой фразы не меняется даже при простом отбрасывании "в том числе": достаточно оставить "и". Будь такое применение данного выражения нормативно признанным, его пришлось бы трактовать как междометие или частицу (запятые при этой присказке разрушают фразу), поскольку при всех прочих применениях перед "в том числе" обязательна запятая . Если же вместо "и" применить "в частности" (и это сохраняет смысл), то нужны две запятые, поскольку нет объединения этих слов с обособленным членом предложения или оборотом (только это убрало бы вторую запятую).

Answer (score 2):

Здесь лучше заменить это выражение на "в частности" - с запятыми. "В том числе" уместнее в случаях, когда вы заранее обозначили, к чему относится "то число". Например, "по внешним причинам, в том числе таким-то".

**P.S.** В отношении уместности употребления союза "в том числе" в том или ином контексте я придерживаюсь точки зрения, близкой к изложенной здесь:

http://www.uralsky-missioner.ru/doc/351

Можно было бы назвать произвольное (без упоминания общего понятия) употребление союза "в том числе" просторечием или (более дипломатично) проявлением разговорного стиля, но, к сожалению, это явление широко распространилось и с ним рано или поздно придётся считаться (например, при письменной передаче речи политиков). Я обратил внимание на него несколько месяцев назад: в полемических ток-шоу это стало приёмом агрессивной аргументации ("я вам в том числе и такой пример приведу" - средство дать понять оппоненту, что у спорщика есть ещё аргументы в запасе и т. п.), причём к этому зачастую участников шоу располагает и манера речи ведущего телепередачи. Произносится "в том числе" (на месте "в частности") с повышением тона на слове "том" (как в китайском втором тоне - от начала слога к концу), что производит впечатление уверенности говорящего в своих словах. Сейчас из телевизора так говорят уже многие и по любому поводу. Тем не менее, я считаю, что в письменной речи таких приёмов следует избегать (для таких контекстов есть "в частности", "в числе прочего").

**в том числе** (союз)
*Употребляется при присоединении члена предложения, который является **частью целого** (**о котором говорится в первой части предложения**), соответствуя по значению сл.: включая кого-либо или что-либо, в том числе и.*
Толковый словарь Ефремовой. Т. Ф. Ефремова. 2000.

**в частности** (вводное слово)
Выделяется знаками препинания, обычно запятыми. Слова «в частности» в составе присоединительного оборота обособляются вместе с относящимися к ним словами.

*Шелленберг, в частности, организовал снабжение немецких частей, стоявших на Атлантическом валу, английским автоматическим оружием.* Ю. Семенов, Семнадцать мгновений весны.

*Желание полного уничтожения неудавшейся жизни на планете, охватившее его потомков, реализовалось, в частности, в бегстве предков тормансиан.* И. Ефремов, Час быка.

(Словарь-справочник по пунктуации. — М.: Справочно-информационный интернет-портал ГРАМОТА.РУ. В. В. Свинцов, В. М. Пахомов, И. В. Филатова. 2010. )
http://punktuaciya.academic.ru/116/%D0%B2_%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8

***Несомненно, эти изменения происходят, в частности, в связи с кризисными явлениями в экономике.***

Answer (score 1):

Несомненно, эти изменения происходят в том числе и в связи с кризисными явлениями в экономике.

Отсутствие запятой здесь совершенно очевидно, и правил никаких не нужно. Дело в том, что оборот входит в основную структуру предложения, поэтому его нельзя обособить. Первая часть предложения "эти изменения происходят" требует обязательного продолжения (по принципу тема - рема, предмет - сообщение о предмете).

Для сравнения (обычный вариант с обособлением): Несомненно, эти изменения происходят по разным причинам,  в том числе и в связи с кризисными явлениями в экономике.

Comment: Вера, а применение такого оборота вне связи с общим понятием где-нибудь уже зафиксировано как норма?
Я слышу, как люди употребляют его в начале фразы, отвечают этими словами на отвлечённый вопрос, расставляют "в том числе" по нескольку раз в середине одной и той же фразы - как будто на всякий случай предупреждая, что только пример чего-то приводят. В своё время столь же обильно применяли оборот "как бы", но это прошло.

Comment: Если рассматривать только грамматику, то получается, что в данном предложении мы не называем множество, в который включается оборот, что и является следствием отсутствия обособления в виде исключения. Но тогда "множество" должно быть как-то обозначено в предыдущей фразе. В противном случае это воспринимается как нарушение грамматики, да и вообще пока неприятно на слух.

Comment: Я могу себе представить предыдущую фразу только с буквальной трактовкой "числа" :)

Число пессимистически настроенных граждан в Греции стало увеличиваться.